Recommendation to learn cohomology and homotopy theory
I learned about the fundamental group and homology theory in Lee’s intro to topological manifolds, part 2 of Munkres and some chapters of Munkres’ elements of algebraic topology. I then polished my knowledge of homology by reading some sections of Hatcher. However, I now want to learn cohomology and homotopy theory, and Hatcher is way too difficult as an introduction. I also dislike Munkres because on the emphasis put on Simplical complexes. Are there any resources that cover roughly the same basic topics in cohomology theory as Hatcher (cohomology rings, duality in manifolds) and other introductions to homotopy theory ?

Try Fulton's "Algebraic Topology." Maybe you will find it easier than Hatcher's book.

I think if you want to build intuition for cohomology of manifolds, a good place to start is Bott and Tu's book Differential Forms in Algebraic Topology. This is not the most general development of cohomology of topological spaces, but I found that it was the most intuitive treatment (though this reflects my own personal biases!)

What do you think is too difficult about Hatcher? Generally speaking, most algebraic topology textbooks should suit your need, but personally speaking I don't find the presentation in most books significantly easier than that of Hatcher. I recommend looking at e.g. "Topology and Geometry" (Bredon), "Algebraic Topology" (tom Dieck), together with what has already been mentioned, to get a feel.
